# Subfigure referencing shows Roman number

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats

I am trying to refer figures and subfigures in my thesis. When i refer entire figure( which contains subfigures) I get it correctly as shown Fig. 1.1. Whenever I am referencing a subfigure. It shows roman numeral eg. Fig.I.1(a). How to get it as Fig. 1.1(a). I am adding a minimum working example. First is for main file. and second is chapter file

```
    \documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\cleardoublepage %\cleardoublepage %for openright

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{CHAPTER}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}%chapter number in roman
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}

\setcounter{section}{0}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
\setcounter{figure}{0}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}
\begin{document}

%\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}

\include{MWCchapter_01}




\end{document}
```

Chapter MWC

```
\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{General}


If I refer entire figure I get it properly as Fig. \ref{Figure}. However if I refer subfigures, it shows roman numeral 
Fig.\ref{FigureA} and 
Fig. \ref{FigureB}  which I dont want (it should be shown as Fig. 1.1(a) and Fig. 1.1(b)). The figures, subfigure captions and numbering are proper. However the problem comes during referencing.

%

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\subfigure[FigureA]{%
\includegraphics[width=3in]{FigureA}
\label{FigureA}}
\subfigure[FigureB]{%
\includegraphics[width=3in]{FigureB}
\label{FigureB}}
\caption{Figure}
\label{Figure}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: It is almost impossible to help you unless you provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: I am using it for thesis. In thesis, the coding has been done so that chapter number is shown in Roman. However, i want the figures and subfigures to be shown in normal (arabic) numeral

Comment: Well, I'm tempted to tell you to use something like `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}` but I can't because I do not know what side effects this will have. People here really wish to provide you with a real answer that does not cause any problems, and this is only possible on the basis of an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: The code you've posted gives no clue as to *why* objects of type `figure` are numbered using uppercase-Roman numerals. You really have to tell us which document class you employ and if your preamble contains any instructions that modify the macro `\thefigure`. Also, do tell us whether you load the `subfigure` or the `subfig` package (or some other package that simplifies the creation of subfigure-like objects.

Comment: yes I am using subfigure package. Also i have used \makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}. This displays figures correctly in arabic format. However, when i refer subfigures, it shows in roman eg: Fig. II.2(a)

Comment: The form `II.2(a)` is not the same as `I(a)`, which is the form you provided in the body of the query. Which form is it?

Comment: Its of Form II.2(a).  If I only refer figure, It shows correctly 2.2. But if i refer the subfigure then it shows II.2(a).

Comment: So, there must be something in the code of the document class that's setting this form. Which document class do you employ? Incidentally, the `subfigure` package has been deprecated for my years. Don't use it; use the `subfig` of the `subcaption` package instead.

Comment: Please ask a structured question, containing a MWE that shows us exactly what you get. Getting information scattered over the comment section is tedious for helpers.

Comment: I wouldn't read a document with such a numbering scheme.  It is confusing to the reader.

Comment: Yes thats what I want to avoid (combination of Roman and Arabic).  I think its due to chapter number being in Roman, this is getting reflected in subfigure referencing. To rectify this issue in figure referencing we are using                                                        \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}.       This however does not work when I refer subfigures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `subfigure` package contains the following instruction:

```
\let\p@subfigure=\thefigure
```

This defines the "prefix string" that LaTeX inserts just ahead of `\thesubfigure` during the creation of cross-references to objects of type `subfigure`. Because the code (inappropriately, in my view!) uses the `\let` device to set up the macro `\p@subfigure`, and because `\thefigure` is set by the `report` document class to be a composite of the chapter number (in Roman numerals) and the actual figure number (in arabic numerals), you end up getting strings of the form `I.1(a)`.

The reason `\let` isn't appropriate here is because `\let` makes a static macro definition: the properties of `\thefigure` that are in effect when `\let\p@subfigure=\thefigure` is run, i.e., *during the processing of the code contained in `report.cls`*, continue to be used even after `\thefigure` gets changed later on (in the preamble).

The immediate remedy is to run the following code at the end of the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@subfigure}{\thefigure}
\makeatother
```

The *real remedy*, though, is not to use the `subfigure` package in the first place. It's been deprecated for years and years, and good substitutes -- the `subfig` and `subcaption` packages -- are available.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Add `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}`, `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}`, and `\renewcommand\thesubfloatfigure{\thesection.\themainfigure(\alph{subfloatfigure})}` to your preamble. This works well with `subfigures` environment.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}} % Add this
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}} % Add this
\renewcommand\thesubfloatfigure{\thesection.\themainfigure(\alph{subfloatfigure})} % Add this

\usepackage{blindtext} % generates dummy text


\begin{document}


    \section{Section Title}

        \Blindtext



        \begin{subfigures}

            \begin{figure}
                \centering
                \fbox{\Huge SubFigure a}
                \caption{Sample Image 1}
            \end{figure}

            \begin{figure}
                \centering
                \fbox{\Huge SubFigure b}
                \caption{Sample Image 2}
            \end{figure}

        \end{subfigures}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So this gives what the OP has and does not want. Without knowing what is really going on in the OPs document.

Comment: It was just misreading since 'I' as a roman letter is very similar to '1'. Now it is corrected. It is just a matter of changing the global numbering of sections and figures, and setting the way subfigures are numbered using `\renewcommand\thesubfloatfigure`